# How to set parameters of a webservice call clientside in js?

Tags: web-services, csom, records-management

I try to execute a SP OOTB webservice method clientside. This method has some parameters like "fileToSubmit, Name, DisplayName, Value, Type, Other, recordRouting, sourceUrl, username ". How can I add the parameters in javascript?

```
function SubmitFileClientSide()
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list;
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var totalSelectedItems = CountDictionary(selectedItems);

    if (totalSelectedItems > 0) 
    {
        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);

        for (i in selectedItems) 
        {

            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                // BELOW I NEED TO ADD PARAMETERS, BUT I DONT KNOW HOW

                var soapEnv =
                "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soapenv/envelope/'>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                    <SubmitFile xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/recordsrepository/'>
                      <fileToSubmit>base64Binary</fileToSubmit>
                      <properties>
                        <RecordsRepositoryProperty>
                          <Name>string</Name>
                          <DisplayName>string</DisplayName>
                          <Value>string</Value>
                          <Type>string</Type>
                          <Other>string</Other>
                        </RecordsRepositoryProperty>
                        <RecordsRepositoryProperty>
                          <Name>string</Name>
                          <DisplayName>string</DisplayName>
                          <Value>string</Value>
                          <Type>string</Type>
                          <Other>string</Other>
                        </RecordsRepositoryProperty>
                      </properties>
                      <recordRouting>string</recordRouting>
                      <sourceUrl>string</sourceUrl>
                      <userName>string</userName>
                    </SubmitFile>
                  </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>";

                $.ajax({
                    url: "www.MyCompanyDomainName.com/sites/popo/_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapEnv,
                    complete: processResult,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by parsing your parameter in xml. May be it can work.

```
           $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.MyCompanyDomainName.com/sites/popo/_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: { xml : escape(soapEnv) },
                    complete: processResult,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
                });
```

Comment: Do I need to add the parameter values in the envelope xml? For example <sourceUrl>http://someUrl</sourceUrl>

Comment: Yes. Just convert your xml string to xml by *escape(<Your XML variable>)*

Comment: Is your problem solved by convert your parameter in xml?

Comment: no, I don't know how to add the fileToSubmit value clientside in type base64Binary..